# Place element adjacent to another that is not within the same div-element

Tags: php, html, css, joomla

**Background**
I'm a real green-bean when it comes to CSS (as in I started like a week ago) and have been assigned with the task of constructing our company's homepage. A heads up: I have 0 experience in web development, and when I say 0, I mean that one week ago I thought that CSS was the design world's terminology for object oriented programming and not that it was something you actually write and code in. But it's all fun to learn new things through SO/WC3/Google but I have run into an issue I can't get a grip on.

**Issue**
We're using Joomla as a development kit and specifically the Beez_20 template. As a reference for the issue I'm having I have uploaded a picture [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pchV4.gif). The parentheses show which css file it is located in. I want to put the banner (div.logoheader) adjacent to and below the menu (ul.menu) and avoid the white space in between them (which is the background of div.header). I've seen several posts about how to use position:relative and position:absolute but I can't get that to work when I have the css code in separate css files.

**Trial and error**
What I've done so far is to make the following changes:

- Removed the max-width so that the menus and backgrounds stretch over the entire page
- Put the div#line position:absolute; so that it is always on the top of the page
- Put the ul.menu position:relative, and top:35px left:-10px to put it exactly below the div#line (why this isn't 0 0 I have no idea but it works this way)
- Put the div.logoheader position:relative;

I've tried switching between relative and absolute but I can't seem to get it working. I always end up with a white space between the logoheader and the ul.menu. The tips I've seen is to use both relative and absolute but I don't know how to work that out when the images and elements are located in different css-files.

**Other**
I've noticed that the ul.menu disappears if I change the div#line position from absolute to relative. The div#line then ends up at the bottom of div.logoheader. If I comment out the section in personal.css and position.css the other elements still remain in the same positions.

I'm thinking that this is not something you solve in CSS but you should go into the PHP file but that is just me stabbing in the dark. Grateful for any help I can get on this issue, and let me know if there is additional information that is required.

EDIT: Fixed link

Comment: The link to the image doesn't work.

Comment: Fixed the link, it should work now!

Comment: Thank. Ok, does `div.logoheader` have a top margin, if you inspect the element in something like Chrome Dev Tools, you might get a better view as to why the whitespace is there. Or maybe `ul-menu` has a bottom margin which would also push the logoheader down

Comment: The div.logoheader has the following:
position: relative
margin: 0em 0px 0px !important
in the personal.css file. In the position.css file it has nothing with padding or margin.

EDIT: and the ul.menu has neither padding nor margin as far as I can see.

Comment: If you are really using Beez_2 it is probably worth spending the money to buy the book on Joomla Templates that was written by Angie Radtke who created Beez_2.

Comment: Good idea, I'll look into that. I mean, the correct answer to any questions I might have is to learn CSS, HTML, PHP and Joomla from scratch but I'm not allowed to spend that much time on this :S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try keeping the relative position for the `div.logoheader` and also adding `bottom: 35px;`. This should push it up. It's not the best method, however without seeing a live preview of the template, it's rather hard to give a more accurate answer. So your final code should look like this:

```
div.logoheader {
    position: relative;
    bottom: 35px;
}
```

You may need to change the value `35` according to the spacing. Hope this helps

Comment: Was about to say that this only moved the white space to the section below the picture but I had to refresh the cache and now it works! Thank you!

Comment: I did have to put bottom:0px though and I don't know why, but hey, it works :)

Comment: Unfortunately, this seems to not be the solution. If I change the position of the ul.menu from 35px to 25px or something else the div.logoheader still stays in the same position. What could be the issue?